# Office 365 : Access denied error

Tags: office365-apps

Everything was working fine until morning, but now I am not able to deploy my office app to Sharepoint server. It throws access denied error.

Please suggest the way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint service was downgraded, maybe some maintenance going on. I was able to login after an hour or so.